# How to setup external hive meta store in databricks with below configuration?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, databricks, azure-databricks, hive-metastore

I tried the below code to create an external metastore to the azure sql server

BUt getting error that it can not be instantiated and a hive version issue.

spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL .database.windows.net:1433;Initial Catalog=hivemetastore;

```
# Skip this one if <hive-version> is 0.13.x.
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version biltin


spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName <user>
datanucleus.fixedDatastore false
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword <pwd>



spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars /databricks/hive_metastore_jars/*
datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables true

hive.metastore.schema.verification false
hive.metastore.schema.verification.record.version false


spark.databricks.cluster.profile singleNode
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true
spark.master local[*, 4]
```

Comment: post error that you get. And what you did - have you uploaded files to `/databricks/hive_metastore/jars`, etc.? Documentation has troubleshooting guide section, follow the steps there

Comment: Yupp That Doesn't work I tried some different approach

Comment: post error message anyway. without it, it's not possible to understand what is wrong

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks buddy for your suggestion.
I used the below code which is working perfectly fine. On Runtime 7.3 LTS

Comment: https://github.com/gauravegostic/picPost/blob/main/hiveMetaStore%20Config.png?raw=true

Comment: @GauravGangwar if the above solution worked for you, post it as an answer so that it will help other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Find a Solution that works for me.
I used the below code which is working perfectly fine. On Runtime 7.3 LTS

[image]